# How asp.net single web page(aspx) is processed for multiple user

Tags: asp.net

I need complete information about how aspx single page server multiple users as compared to stand alone window application where separate exe is running on each user machine.But how exactly single aspx page serve multiple users at same time.
I search on Google but not get any good example.
I need any article or reference link for understanding the same.

Answer (score 1):

Every request to any ASPX page will create a separate instance of the page class, generally all in the same AppDomain.

There is no concept of a "user", although you can create one using cookies or session state.

Answer (score 0):

### [Choosing Between Windows Forms and Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t6z562c(v=vs.90).aspx)

> **Programming model**
>
> Windows Forms is based on a client-side, Win32 message-pump mode,
> where instances of components are created, used, and discarded by the
> developer.
>
> Web Forms relies on a largely asynchronous, disconnected model, where
> components are loosely coupled to the application front end.
> Typically, application components are invoked through HTTP. This model
> may not be suitable for applications requiring extreme throughput from
> the user end or for those with high-volume transactions. Similarly,
> Web Forms applications may not be suitable for database applications
> that require high levels of concurrency control (for example,
> pessimistic locking).
>
> **Security**
>
> Windows Forms uses permissions in its implementation of code access
> security to protect computer resources and sensitive information. This
> allows careful exposure of functionality, while retaining security.
> For instance, the Printing Permission, which at one level would allow
> printing to the default printer only, at another level would allow
> printing to any printer. Using ClickOnce, developers can easily
> configure which permissions their applications should and should not
> demand from the client. For more information, see ClickOnce Deployment
> and Security.
>
> Authorization to gain access to the resources of a Web application is
> typically controlled on a per-URL basis by authenticating the
> credentials (for example, a name/password pair) of the requestor. Web
> Forms allows the developer to control the identity under which server
> application code is executed. Applications can execute code with the
> identity of the requesting entity, which is known as impersonation.
> Applications can also dynamically tailor content based on the
> requestor's identity or role. For example, a manager could receive
> access to a site, or a higher level of content than someone with lower
> permissions.